# GWT UiHandler for g:Anchor is not firing

Tags: gwt

I essentially have a menu where you can't click the headers, but when you hover over the menu item you can select from the drop down elements.  Each of the elements are g:Anchor tags with ui fields associated to them.  What I would expect to happen, is that when a user clicks on one of the drop down elements, my uiHandler for that field would fire.  Even with debugging on and a break point it doesn't ever hit.

Below you will find the main areas of concern in the code.  I will only post my gwt imports in here, since it can be assumed the rest are correct due to zero errors.

Here is an XML snippet to get an idea of what is going on

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
             xmlns:cpcw='urn:import:org.collegeboard.pa.gwt.client.widget'>
    <cpcw:ExtendedHTMLPanel>
        <ul>
            <li ui:field="juniorHigh"><g:Anchor href="">Junior High</g:Anchor>
            <ul>
                <li><g:Anchor href="#" ui:field="juniorHighFall">Fall</g:Anchor></li>
                <li><g:Anchor href="#" ui:field="juniorHighSpring">Spring</g:Anchor></li>
                <li><g:Anchor href="#" ui:field="juniorHighSummer">Summer</g:Anchor></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </cpcw:ExtendedHTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

And then here are the pieces from my Java class

imports

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.LIElement;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Anchor;
```

Ui Fields

```
@UiField
protected LIElement juniorHigh;

@UiField
protected Anchor juniorHighFall;

@UiField
protected Anchor juniorHighSpring;

@UiField
protected Anchor juniorHighSummer;
```

Ui Handler

```
@UiHandler({"juniorHighFall","juniorHighSpring","juniorHighSummer"})
public void handleMenuClick(ClickEvent event)
{
    DisplayUtil.displayAlertMessage(event.toString());
}
```

Initialize

```
@Override
public void initializeBinder()
{
    initWidget(ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}
```

Now, the UiHandler never actually gets hit.  I have had the g:Anchor tags with and without the href, and also have tried them as g:Hyperlink and g:Button with no success.  It is as if the UiHandler isn't even there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and also if you feel you would need anything else for troubleshooting, please let me know!!

Thanks :-)

EDIT:

Just to make sure that this was clear, the template ui.xml file that contained this ui.xml file was placing this in a div.  When I replaced that with a SimplePanel, everything worked with the UiHandler.

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does and should work as you have it by default.

I've noticed:

- Your code references "ourUiBinder"
- Your controls are wrapped in a "ExtendedHTMLPanel"

These seem like custom classes - perhaps something funky is going on in those implementations?

Maybe you can try wrapping those anchors in a SimplePanel and using the default UiBinder and see if that works. If it does, chances are it's something to do with any custom controls you use. If it doesn't then something strange is going on - maybe restart your IDE etc.

Comment: Yeah, they are custom classes, and I will start to dig into them to see if there is something funky going on with them.  Thank you for the reassurance that the code should work, because that was driving me up the wall!

I will also give SimplePanel a shot to see if that does the trick!  Thanks for the response!

Comment: Also, I would upvote this, but I don't have enough reputation on here yet to do so...

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: The SimplePanel did the trick!  On the template xml which contains this ExtendedHTMLPanel, the elements were divs.  I changed the divs to SimplePanels and all UiHandlers are working properly.  I still dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer, but thank you!  :)

Answer (score 2):

The Template xml file had each view contained in a div element.  Filip-fku recommended I look into SimplePanels for the code I posted, which made me go look at the template file as well to see they were not GWT containers at all, they were divs.  As soon as I made them SimplePanels my UiHandlers worked like a charm!

Thank you Filip-fku!  g:SimplePanel FTW!!!